# zend framework view helper

Tags: zend-framework

I want to make a view helper for my whole website.

Which fetches entity_names from database every time i will give entity_id as peramater in helper function.

Is it possible using view helper?

If any other simple way is there pls tell me.

In sort i want to make a common helper  for my whole website for some sort of database queries like getting names by id's.

Comment: Yes this is possible and pretty much the intended use of view helpers (if I get your use correct). You might have to get a bit more concrete if you problems with implementing it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this belongs in the view but rather the model part of your application. Getting stuff off the database is the model's responsibility, not the view.

Here's a similar question that might point you in the right direction: [php design question - will a Helper help here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298220/php-design-question-will-a-helper-help-here/4298660#4298660)