# php design question - will a Helper help here?

Tags: php, zend-framework, design-patterns, zend-db

I have to list several elements that are coming from a database source A and they are:
team_id, team_name and team_score (translated for explanation sake).

I need to loop over them, and display that information.

So, I have, on the DAO side:

```
public function listOfTeams()
{
  $select = $this->select()
    ->from(array('t'=>'teams'), array('cod_team','name','score'));
  return $this->fetchAll($select);

}
```

On my team controller:

```
public function listAction()
{
  $teamsDao = new TeamsDao();
  $this->view->infoTeam = $teamsDao->listOfTeams();                    
}
```

And at the view:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++): ?>

  <?php if(isset($this->infoTeam[$i])): ?>
```

Now, the thing is, on each of those listed items, I need to add more information.

That information doesn't come directly from a database, but it's a result of some calculations.

Take for example the percentage of games done. (translated);

```
$totalGamesNumber > 0 ? ($gamesDone*100)/$totalGamesNumber : 0);
```

So, I need to grab the total games number from the database, then, for each team, I need to have the number of games done, so that I can have the percentage to be displayed.

The $gamesDone are obtained by:

```
$gameTeamDao->countGamesPerTeam($gameVo, $teamVo);
```

*I'm stuck here, because I cannot see where/how should I call and make the method for calculating the percentage, in order to allow the percentage of games completed to be presented along with the other data.*

*Can I have some help out of this mud ?*

If you had to write a helper for this, more or less, how will it looked like?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

PS - If you need more detailed information. I can provide. I could be forgeting something that for me is taken, but that, for those who want to help it isn't. So, just let me know. Thanks a lot again.

Update: translated all post to English for help sake.

Comment: please clarify the question. To me it's not clear why you cannot simply put that calculation into a helper and output it where needed. Also, this is using ZF, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Yes I can put that information into a Helper. My question is, is that the appropriate place? If so, what specific information should I pass to that helper? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gordon: To put in on other terms, if you or anyone else could see this, and noted that a helper will be a nice thing to do, how would the helper look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using ZF, you could make all this computations in the table row's class. Here's how. Let's say your teams class is called Application_Model_DbTable_Teams.

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Teams extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'teams'; // table name
    protected $_id = 'teamId'; // table primary key

    // rows returned by fetchAll() will be of this class
    protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_DbRow_Teams';

}
```

Then you need to create the Application_Model_DbRow_Teams class where you will put the extra calculations

```
class Application_Model_DbRow_Teams extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    public $percentGamesDone;

    public function init()
    {
        // This method gets called automatically by ZF when you instantiate a new
        // object from this class
        // This is where you will put your extra calculations, 
        // like percentage games done, etc
        $this->percentGamesDone = $this->getPercentGames();
    }

    public function getPercentGames() 
    {
        $calculation = 3; // replace this with real data
        return $calculation;
    }
}
```

Once you've done this, you can simply use any of the row's declared properties (like percentGameDone) directly from the view as they will be calculated right when you instanciate the rows.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing: These calculations belong in the model, not in view helpers.

Comment: @Julian: the classes are already created. They both extend Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract and they are called: class TeamDao and class GameDao (is that an issue over your implementation suggestion?).

Comment: I also use getters and setters, and perhaps I can pass public $percentGamesDone; by a VO ?

Comment: @MEM, there WILL be an issue if both classes extend Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract. The class that describes the table should extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and the class that describes the row should extend Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract. There is no problem on using getters and setters (in fact I believe that is the right way of going about it), but I'm not sure why you named your classes TeamDao and GameDao since they will be dealing with team info only. Inside the TeamsDao class you should be calculating the games data. By the way, what do you mean by VO? :)

Comment: @Julian: Thanks. By Vo I mean Value Object with is, a class containing getters and setters. Both DAO and VO classes are related with database table information, just a way for organizing things. Here, GameDao will deal with all model methods related to the Game table on the database. TeamDao will have all methods related with Team database table. If I need to deal with Join information on a given method, then what Dao should I choose? Well.. I choose the DAO based on what VO it will accept on that method. Hope this makes sense... :)

Comment: @Julian - 1) Should I put both classes on the same php file? @Julian - 2) It's Application_Model_DbRow_Teams a helper class ?

Comment: @MEM, you shouldn't put them on the same PHP file as Zend Framework will attempt to find them using a path that it gets from the class name (using a few rules). For example: Application_Model_DbRow_Teams would be application/models/DbRow/Teams.php. Notice that "Model" in the class name becomes "models" in the path. I don't think this is strictly a "helper" in ZF lingo. Usually helpers have the "helper" keyword in their class name, altough some don't: Zend_View_Helper_Truncate (view helper), or SomeController_Action (action helper which doesn't contain "helper" in its name).